# Can I set www.something.com to be my AName record

Tags: domains, dns, iis

I was just hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I want to have my website hosted which I want to display as `www.mydomain.com` I also need `mydomain.com` and `blog.mydomain.com` to go to the same IP.

Do I need to create:

1. 1 x AName record for `www.mydomain.com` which points at my server static URL
2. Then create 2 x CName records which both point at `www.mydomain.com`

?

Because if thats the way it's done then I want to set a redirect up on my IIS server to 301 to `www.mydomain.com` if it sees the URL as `mydomain.com`.

Does this sound okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should set three **A records** poiting to your server IP.

   - `*.mydomains.com`
   - `www.mydomain.com`
   - `blog.mydomain.com`
2. Then you need to set up your Virtual Host correctly to accept requests for all three domains/subdomains (see e.g. [Virtual hosting with IIS (Internet Information Services)](http://support.simpledns.com/KB/a82/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services.aspx) or [Setting Host Headers in IIS 6.0](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/)).
3. Redirect needed domains to one desired domain using **URL Rewrite module** and **301 redirect** (e.g. both `www` and `blog` to `mydomain.com`) so you don't have "duplicate" content.

Comment: What is wrong with using CNAME?

Comment: I wouldn't say _wrong_, BUT: 1) two DNS queries instead of have to be done, 2) it might get a bit confusing e.g. with MX records (might not work as expected :-)), 3) and most important: **Canonical Name** is an alias, so if you type alias into the browser (e.g. **with** WWW) it won't change to **non-WWW** version, which might not be the best behavior (e.g. for SEO reasons).

Comment: [How does pointing a domain via a CNAME record affect the SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47169/how-does-pointing-a-domain-via-a-cname-record-affect-the-seo)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You may find the [Wikipedia article on CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cname) informative.

Comment: "Yes" and a link is _not_ an answer - it's a comment. Please view the FAQ's for this site on Answers.

Comment: Link only answers are not appropriate.  Links break, information on other sites goes away.  Please either explain in your own words what the other site says or use a blockquote from the other site.